# web app hosted on GCP VM not accessible on certain internet connections

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, web-applications, google-compute-engine, firewall

I have deployed a web application on a GCP VM. Both the Django backend (running on port 8000) and react build files (on nginx port 8080) are running normally within the VM. Also, I was able to set a domain and the application is accessible when I try it.

I have a firewall set up in order to block all external access that's not limited to the ports the application uses. (Only ports 8080 and 8000 are usable) In addition to that, HTTP/HTTPS connections have been enabled through the firewall configuration.

I noticed that some clients are reporting that they are unable to access the application. I did some investigating and it seems that their backend requests are not going through. The issue persists on certain internet connections and is not device-related.

I have ran a similar setup previously with no notable issues. I would appreciate it if someone could guide me through the steps of troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: I had similar issue with a website, and deactivating the IPv6 on my network adapter (on my workstation) solved the issue. You can try this way...

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Do you mean changing a config on my laptop? or on the router itself? because I am able to access the web app from the same laptop on a different internet connection.

Comment: @ Mohamad El Baba, Do they experience a timeout, or do they get a specific HTTP return code? If FW rules logging is enabled then share the logs for troubleshooting  further steps.

Comment: I got timeout. And yes with the same laptop (on windows) you can change the network adapter property and unselect IPv6 support. It might be a dead end, but it's quick and easy to test!

Comment: @Rameshkollisetty the connection doesn't get established so the connection times out after a while. However, when I run a VPN I have no issue connecting to the server.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it didn't work. I need a more permanent solution anyway. thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: @MohamadElBaba Need stack details 
however try:
1. Turning on and off the firewall. If that works, try configuring the [firewall properly] (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls), If firewall is not the problem try creating the client's scenario with various parameters.
2.Also try [enabling and disabling https] (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs).
3.If you are still facing issues just in case create another VM, move your resources there and [reconfigure DNS] (https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the port that I was using for my Django application. Port 8000 was not working properly even after creating a new image of the machine and testing the application there. After switching to port 5000 everything seemed to be working normally.

***Although the comments on this post did not work for me, these steps should be followed in order to troubleshoot similar issues:***

1. Disable the IPV6 adapter on your machine (In case the issue is
   device-specific)
2. Re-deploy the same application on another VM instance as faulty
   hardware exists and similar issues can happen (for any cloud
   service)
3. Make sure there is no firewall on the level of the host (check
   firewall by SSH-ing into the machine)
4. Make sure that the port is not being used by another
   application/service
5. Make sure the port is not blocked in the firewall settings (firewall
   service that manages connections to the machine)
6. Try a new port if all else fails